# Random number generation in multiple objects of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, random

In this example code, I am creating 100 objects in a list with random x values, but the problem is that all of the created objects have the same x value. I tried searching web for solutions for this but I couldn't find any.

```
import random
list = []
class object:
    x = random.randint(1,1000)

for i in range(1,101):
    list.append(object())

for i in range(1,100):
    print(list[i].x)
```

Comment: 1. You're shadowing the built-in object; and 2. you only pick a random number *once*. You shouldn't do either of those things.

Comment: You're using a class variable instead of an instance variable. You should be doing: `class A:
 def __init__(self):
  self.x = random.randint(1, 1000)`

Comment: You're also shadowing the built-in `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) in the Python Docs to get clarification on your specific confusion.

> Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by all instances of the class:
>
> ````py
> class Dog:
>
>     kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
>
> >>> d = Dog('Fido')
> >>> e = Dog('Buddy')
> >>> d.kind                  # shared by all dogs 'canine'
> >>> e.kind                  # shared by all dogs 'canine'
> >>> d.name                  # unique to d 'Fido'
> >>> e.name                  # unique to e 'Buddy' ```
> ````

---

What you are looking for, as @rassar suggested, is:

```py
class Obj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(1,1000)

a = Obj()
b = Obj()
c = Obj()

print(a.x, b.x, c.x)
```